# I am Using Facebook API.How to get Mobile Number?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

```
      FB.api('/me', 'GET', { fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,email' }, function (response) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "id= " + response.id + "  ****** Email= " + response.email + " *****  Name= " + response.first_name + " " + response.last_name ;
        });
```

I am using the above code to get information.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow.
So the code here - is it working? is it not working? what is the error you get when you try it? what were you expecting to get? what did you find when you googled for what you want? what happened when you tried the suggestions from google? ie: you haven't given us enough information to help you. Can you please edit your question and add everything you've tried? We expect you to have had a go at it yourself before you come here...

Answer (score 6):

The `user_address` and `user_mobile_phone` permissions have been removed. Please see this post for more info.

Please Refer [Facebook developer's Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/)